# Connect to multiple Kafka servers using springboot

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kerberos, spring-kafka

In Spring boot application, I want to connect to 2 different kafka servers simultaneously. I am using KafkaAdmin and AdminClient to make the connection and perform CRUD Operations.

```
@Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();

        String krb5location = krb5Location;
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", krb5location);
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", jaasConfigLocation);

        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, server);
        configs.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
        configs.put("ssl.truststore.location", sslTruststoreLocation);
        configs.put("ssl.truststore.password", sslTruststorePassowrd);

        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }

    @Bean
    @PostConstruct
    public AdminClient config() {

        return AdminClient.create(kafkaAdmin.getConfig());

    }
```

Similarly server 2 is configured in same springboot application.

If I load configuration of both kafka server at once during app initialization following error is displayed

```
>>>KRBError:
     cTime is Sun Jun 03 14:23:02 IST 2001 991558382000
     sTime is Tue Nov 20 10:46:53 IST 2018 1542691013000
     suSec is 512097
     error code is 7
     error Message is Server not found in Kerberos database
     cname is config1@servername.com
     sname is config2@servernname.com
     msgType is 30
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(KrbTgsRep.java:73)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.getReply(KrbTgsReq.java:251)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.sendAndGetCreds(KrbTgsReq.java:262)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:308)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.acquireServiceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:126)
    at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.acquireServiceCreds(Credentials.java:458)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Krb5Context.java:693)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:248)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$2.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:361)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$2.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:359)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:359)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.sendSaslClientToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:269)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:81)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:474)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:412)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1006)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: KrbException: Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.KDCRep.init(KDCRep.java:140)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.TGSRep.init(TGSRep.java:65)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.TGSRep.<init>(TGSRep.java:60)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(KrbTgsRep.java:55)
    ... 22 more
2018-11-20 10:46:53.605 ERROR 8672 --- [| adminclient-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-4] Connection to node -1 failed authentication due to: An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7) - UNKNOWN_SERVER)]) occurred when evaluating SASL token received from the Kafka Broker. This may be caused by Java's being unable to resolve the Kafka Broker's hostname correctly. You may want to try to adding '-Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1=dns,sun' to your client's JVMFLAGS environment. Users must configure FQDN of kafka brokers when authenticating using SASL and `socketChannel.socket().getInetAddress().getHostName()` must match the hostname in `principal/hostname@realm` Kafka Client will go to AUTHENTICATION_FAILED state.
```

Comment: Replacing the system property is not a good idea - it's shared.

Comment: Based on the question, it's hard to say that there's two clusters you're connecting to, but the error seems straightforward, and it's not a Spring issue... Note that Kafka clients only connect to one broker, then bootstrap the rest of the same cluster already